# Refused to load the image after using DomSanitizer

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that loads an image from a server and I want to display that image within a `<img [src]="imageURL">` tag.
I used the `DomSanitizer` to make that URL safe, but I'm still getting unsafe errors and the image is not showing.

Within my **file.service.ts** I have this function:

```
downloadResource(downloadUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(downloadUrl, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'accept': 'application/octet-stream',
        'content-type': 'application/json'}),
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    });
  }
```

The function works fine for downloading images and other files.

Then, in my **image.component.ts** I call the function like this:

```
imageURL: any;

  constructor(private fileService: FileService, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileService.downloadResource(downloadUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
        this.imageURL = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    });
  }
```

And my **image.component.html** looks like this:

```
<img [src]="imageURL">
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Refused to load the image 'blob:https://someurl.72726' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data:".

I also tried: `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` but I'm getting the same error.

Am I missing something?

Edit:
When I print the `imageURL`on the console I'm getting this:

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding: blob:https://someurl.72726 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: might have something to do with the actual object url... can you show us the `imageURL` string as well?

Comment: @KelvinLai I edited my question and added the output of the `imageURL`.